# R: Error in if argument is of length zero

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a vector like this:

```
x <- c(0.9,0.9,0,0,0.9,0,0.8)
```

I want to eliminate all the zeros and create a new vector from it, so I have created this if statement:

```
if (x[i] == 0) {
y <- x[-(i)]}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in if (x[i] == 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want `y <- x[x!=0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a `for` loop with `if/else`.  It can be simply done with vectorization

```
y <- x[x != 0]
```

Create the logical vector with expression `x != 0` , use that to subset (`?Extract` with square brackets) the original vector and assign the output vector to a variable with identifier 'y'